# Resetting position to original with AngularMaterial + cdkDrag

Tags: angular-material, angular-cdk

I created an image viewer that enables you to zoom and drag the image around. It's working fine, with one problem, I can't find a native way with Material CDK to reset the image to the original position when the image source is changed like I am doing for image scaling in this example:

```js
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() src: string;
  @Input() height: number;
  @Input() alt: string;
  @Input() zoomFactor = 0.1;
  @Input() wheelZoom = 0.1;

  get transform() {
    const transform = `translate(${this.translateX}px, ${this.translateY}px) rotate(${this.rotation}deg) scale(${this.scale})`;
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(transform);
  }

  public fullscreen = false;
  public loading = true;
  public scale = 1;
  private rotation = 0;
  private translateX = 0;
  private translateY = 0;
  private prevX: number;
  private prevY: number;
  private hovered = false;

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.src) {
      this.scale = 1;
    }
  }

  //......
```